# Versiones de APP de desarrollo y producción en el mismo móvil

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic, ionic-framework, ionic4

Estoy realizando una APP con Ionic (4).

He comprobado que una vez instalada una APK en el móvil (versión de desarrollo), si luego quieres instalarte la versión que se sube a Google Play Console (versión de producción), aunque los nombres de las APP sean diferentes, Google la detecta como la misma aplicación y no da la opción de instalar la otra versión.

Es posible tener instaladas en el mismo dispositivo una versión de desarrollo y una de producción

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si deseas que la app que creas sobreescriba a una anterior, el valor que debes modificar es el `versionCode` dentro de tu `build.gradle` , este debe ser un valor consecutivo mayor.

```
android {
      ...
      defaultConfig {
        ...
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
      }
      productFlavors {
        demo {
          ...
          versionName "1.1-demo"
        }
        full {
          ...
        }
      }
    }
```

Revisa:
https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning

---

**Para tener en un solo dispositivo la versiòn de desarrollo y producciòn ùnicamente se puede realizar si el package name de ambas aplicaciones es diferente.**

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero no es lo que estoy buscando. Lo que necesito saber es como tener las dos versiones (desarrollo y producción) en el mismo dispositivo.